# Configuring RSS feed in MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I am trying to configure RSS feed for a pages library in MOSS. The requirement is fairly simple, it includes:

1. display the page title
2. display the page description (short summary)
3. filter the feed by the content type

I have done the following:

1. enable RSS feed in site collection
2. enable and configure the RSS feed on the list to display the description
3. create custom view to filter by content type

However, the feed is displaying page file name instead of page title.

Anyone know if I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

I found this when searching for an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232690/removing-column-name-from-sharepoint-rss-feed). The solution I found might help you but it seems overkill for what you're trying to achieve. I haven't worked with the SharePoint RSS feed much so I have no idea if there's a simpler way to get replace the page name with the title. Still, check [this article out](http://www.thesug.org/Blogs/kyles/archive/2009/04/17/SharePoint_RSS_Feeds_UNHINGED.aspx.aspx) and see if it helps.

Also I just noticed the question date...but I've already typed all this...so...yeah.