# Removing column name from SharePoint RSS feed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, rss

I have a SharePoint 2007 site the exposes RSS feeds to a static HTML page. The static page will aggregate and display them via jQuery AJAX. The problem is that SharePoint [includes the name and value of the columns](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-rss-feeds-HA010021425.aspx) in the body of the feed *(go to link and search for `body`)* which makes my page look like this:

[image]

Note the **Body:** after the date and before the description. I don't want that there column names in the feed. How do I tell SharePoint to exclude the column names? Here is a section of the feed. You can See **Body** is included in the feed item description.

```
<item>
    <title>Sample Post #3</title>
    <link>http://example.com/ViewPost.aspx?ID=4</link>
    <description><![CDATA[<div><b>Body:</b> <div class=ExternalClass2325D3CC73DB4C30BE5AB60A06E681F9><div>
        <div id=lipsum>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... </p>
        </div></div></div></div>
        <div><b>Category:</b> Category 1</div>
        <div><b>Published:</b> 12/29/2011 9:11 PM</div>
    ]]></description>
    <!--extraneous elements deleted for brevity -->
</item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this source](http://www.thesug.org/Blogs/kyles/archive/2009/04/17/SharePoint_RSS_Feeds_UNHINGED.aspx.aspx) it's not a very quick and easy thing to do but it can be done. It involves creating your own XSL style sheet (or copying the default one and modifying it) and updating the SharePoint web.config to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Read the source you're pointing to, it tells you that the column title is displayed if you reference several columns in your RSS settings. If you only reference one column, the column name should not be displayed.

As you are using jQuery AJAX, you could parse the RSS content after you retrieve it, and remove the column names. Your other option is to change your RSS settings to have only one column displayed.

Comment: I read that part and I'm not allowed to remove the other columns. Maybe I should have said that but I was trying to keep the question concise.